# Spotify Preview API: player.change event not fired on queued tracks

Tags: spotify, spotify-queue

When playing from a playlist in Spotify, if I queue a track from somewhere else than the playlist currently playing (for example from a search result), the player's change event is not fired when the queued track starts playing.

Are anyone else experiencing this? Is the change event only supposed to be fired within the playing context? If so, how do I get track info when playing queued tracks?

Comment: How are you queuing the tracks?

Comment: Step by step:
1: Search for "royals" (for example).
2: Right-click one of the results and click "Queue".
3: Go to the App.
4: Skip to next track, the event is not fired.

If you change step 2, for example go to the album and then queue the track from there, the event is fired in step 4. Do you experience the same behavior?

Answer (score 0):

What did you do?

Try something like this:

```
    models.player.addEventListener('change:track', updateCurrentTrack);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have tried. updateCurrentTrack() is called whenever the track changes within the playlist, but when playback of a track queued from a search result starts, it is not called. When playback of the queued track is finished, and playback from the playlist resumes, updateCurrentTrack() is called again.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old, but for reference, you should be able to do something like this:

```
models.player.addEventListener('change', updateCurrentTrack);

function updateCurrentTrack(){
    models.player.load('track').done(function (player) {
        if(player.track.uri != currentTrack.uri){
            currentTrack = player.track;
            //enter code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the 'change'-event is not fired when playing tracks queued from a search result. I've tested it on several computers, running both Windows, OSX and Linux. Same behavior on all.